# Mock different results of an api called inside react component in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component that calls an API that returns two different results which the default value is

```json
{init:false}
```

And based on users actions, it will be true:

```json
{init:true}
```

Now I want to test these two states in my `app.test.tsx`, It will work when I skip one of them(each working fine without another one):

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { render } from 'src/mocks/renderViaAllProviders';
import App from './app';
import * as apis from 'src/api/consul';
import { mockedRawConsul } from 'src/mocks/db/consul';

test("Show init page when 'initialized:false' in consul.", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  const loading = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /loading/i });
  expect(loading).toBeInTheDocument();

  const initTitle = await screen.findByRole('heading', {
    name: /init page/i
  });
  expect(initTitle).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test("Show Login page when 'initialized:true' in consul", async () => {
  const initializedConsul = {
    ...mockedRawConsul,
    ...{ configs: { initialized: true } }
  };
  /*eslint-disable */
  //@ts-ignore
  apis.getConsulPublicConfig = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve(initializedConsul)
  );

  render(<App />);
  const loginButton = await screen.findByRole('button', {
    name: /regularLogin/i
  });
  expect(loginButton).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

How can I fix this?

**Update**

Here is the [reprex](https://github.com/web-reprex/panel-jest-api-mocking) and the error :

```sh
● Show Login page when 'initialized:true' in consul

    Unable to find role="textbox"

    console.error
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
          at onResponseRejected (\src\api\
service\interceptors.ts:18:23)
          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
          at getLicense (\src\api\license .

ts:10:20)
```

Comment: Show the code under test

Comment: when you run both of the  test cases it is failing, if failing can you share which individual test case is failing along with the error

Comment: @ravi , It does not matter, skipping each one, will make the test pass, but both together will fail..

Comment: @slideshowp2 , I've added the reprex

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to simulate the example that you are trying, I am able to mock the API which returns different results and test for the same, but since we want different results when a Component is rendered the API will be called only once(assuming the API is called on mounting) and upon some user actions the Component will be mounted again that's why called render function again not sure whether it is a good practice or not

```
//App.js
 export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('loading');
  const [show, setShow] = useState({init: false})

  useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setValue('init page')
        fetchData().then(data => {
          setShow(data)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(`ERROR`)
        })
      },0)
  },[])

  
  const { init = false} = show
  return (
    <>
      <p>IT S APP</p>
      <h1>Value is {value}</h1>
      { init ? <button>regular Login</button> : null}
    </>
  );
}

//api.js
function fetchData() {
   return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((response) =>
      Promise.resolve({init: true})
    );
}  
export { fetchData };

//App.test.js
import App from "./App";
import { fetchData }from './api';
jest.mock('./api')

describe("<App />", () => {
  it("check if loading, login button is present",async () => {
    fetchData.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({init: false}))
    fetchData.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({init: true}))
    render(<App />);
    
    const loading = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /loading/i });
    expect(loading).toBeInTheDocument();

    const initTitle = await screen.findByRole('heading', {
      name: /init page/i
    });
    expect(initTitle).toBeInTheDocument();

    render(<App />);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByRole('button', {
        name: /regular Login/i
      })).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: @SeyyedKhandon no

Comment: Can you please test it?